# How to check to true a list of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using React and Redux in order to manage the state of a list of checkboxes. What I have so far is working but eslint is sending me back an error:

> assignment to property of function parameter

So I think I am doing something wrong.

This is the component:

```
import { toggleCheckboxAction, setCheckboxesToChecked } from '../actions/cancellations';

const CheckboxList = ({
  columnsFilterHandler,
  setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler,
  checkboxes,
  t,
}) => {
  const onChange = (value, id, event) => {
    const item = checkboxes.slice().find(idx => idx.id === id);
    if (item) {
      item.checked = !item.checked;
      columnsFilterHandler(value, id, event.target.value);
      return { checkboxes };
    }
    return item;
  };

  const setCheckboxesToTrue = () => {
    const items = checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked === false);
    items.map(item => {
      if (item) {
        item.checked = !item.checked; // LINE THROWING THE WARNING
        setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler(item.checked);
      }
      return item;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToolbarTitle title="Columns" />
      <ToolbarOption>
        <Button kind="ghost" small onClick={setCheckboxesToTrue}>
          {t('cancellations.resetDefault')}
        </Button>
      </ToolbarOption>
      {checkboxes.map(checkbox => (
        <ToolbarOption>
          <Checkbox
            key={checkbox.id}
            id={checkbox.id}
            labelText={checkbox.labelText}
            value={checkbox.value}
            checked={checkbox.checked}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        </ToolbarOption>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

CheckboxList.propTypes = {
  columnsFilterHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  checkboxes: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({})).isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  checkboxes: state.cancellations.checkboxes,
});

export default compose(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    dispatch => ({
      columnsFilterHandler: (value, isChecked, valueName) => {
        dispatch(toggleCheckboxAction(value, isChecked, valueName));
      },
      setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler: isChecked => {
        dispatch(setCheckboxesToChecked(isChecked));
      },
    }),
  ),
)(translate()(CheckboxList));
```

On the `onChange` function is where I play with the checkboxes, setting them to `checked` or `!checked`.

The issue comes from the function `setCheckboxesToTrue` on the line `item.checked = !item.checked;`

This is the action:

```
const setCheckboxesToChecked = isChecked => ({
  type: ActionTypes.CHECKED_ALL_CHECKBOXES,
  payload: { isChecked },
});
```

And this is the reducer to set them `true` or `false`:

```
[ActionTypes.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      checkboxes: initialState.checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return checkbox;
        }
        return {
          ...checkbox,
          checked: !checkbox.checked,
        };
      }),
    };
  },
```

And this should be the reducer to set them all to `true`:

```
[ActionTypes.CHECKED_ALL_CHECKBOXES](state, action) {
    return {
      ...state,
      checkboxes: initialState.checkboxes.map(checkbox => {
        if (checkbox.id !== action.payload.id) {
          return checkbox;
        }
        return {
          ...checkbox,
          checked: checkbox.checked,
        };
      }),
    };
  },
```

Do you guys know a better way to do what I am attempting to do or something to fix the error I am getting?

Answer (score 0):

So, ESLint is complaining for exactly the reason it says: you are modifying the value of a function parameter. While this is perfectly valid JS and will work, it's highly discouraged because it makes it very easy to create bugs. Specifically:

```
items.map(item => {
  if (item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked; // HERE, you modify `item` which is the parameter passed to the map callback function
    setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler(item.checked);
  }
  return item;
});
```

What you should do (and have done elsewhere in your code so you might have just forgotten to here):

```
items.map(item => {
  const newItem = { ...item }; // Create a copy of `item` so that you don't need to modify the one coming in as the function parameter
  if (item) {
    newItem.checked = !newItem.checked;
    setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler(newItem.checked);
  }
  return newItem;
});
```

Comment: The warning is gone but now the functionality is not working as it was. I mean, now it is not setting the whole list checkboxes to true.

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What's not working?

Comment: As it was before it was setting the whole list checkboxes to true. After I applied this change, now it is not working. The function setCheckboxesToTrue is not setting the checkboxes to true.

Comment: Can you show the code for `setCheckboxesToChecked` please?

Comment: It is below: `This is the action:` in my post

Comment: Oh, sorry. In your main block of code you call it `setCheckboxesToCheckedHandler`. Looking now

Comment: I changed this line: `const newItem = item;` instead of `const newItem = {...item};` and it worked.

Comment: My guess is that there is a problem somewhere else. `const newItem = {...item};` should work. In fact, `const newItem = item;` is the exact same problem as ESLint was pointing out originally: you are going to modify the existing object rather than create a new one. You can easily see this by testing this code in the browser console: `const x = {}; const y = x; y.foo = 'bar'; console.log(x);` You'll see that `x` was modified, because `y` is just a reference to `x`

Comment: So maybe the issue is coming from the reducer/action?

Comment: I think I know the issue. Your reducer relies on being able to read `payload.id`, but the only thing you are putting in the `payload` (in the action) is `payload: { isChecked }`

Comment: Mmm but then why this way doesn't work `const newItem = item;` if it is a copy of the same object? How could that change?

Comment: Hmm. Not totally sure without testing, but my guess is that by modifying the parameter value you are actually modifying the value in the Redux store. Each `item` is actually a reference to an index of `checkboxes`. I bet if you were to move your Rexus store to use Immutable.js, it would be yelling at you for trying to change a value that shouldn't be changed manually